# getting column names + iterating + ordering + awk

Tags: bash, awk

this is my file

```
$ cat -v test6 | head
"Rec_Open_Date"|"MSISDN"|"IMEI"|"Data_Volume_Bytes"|"Device_Manufacturer"|"Device_Model"|"Product_Description"|"Data_Volume_MB"|">20MB/30"|">200MB/30"|">2048MB/30"|">5120MB/30"|">10240MB/30"
"2015-10-06"|"427"|"060"|"137765"|"Samsung Korea"|"Samsung SM-G900I"|"$39 Plan"|"0.131383"|"0"|"0"|"0"|"0"|"0"
"2015-10-06"|"592"|"620"|"0"|"Apple Inc"|"Apple iPhone 6 (A1586)"|"PREPAY  STD - TRIAL - #16"|"0"|"0"|"0"|"0"|"0"|"0"
"2015-10-06"|"007"|"290"|"0"|"Apple Inc"|"Apple iPhone 6 (A1586)"|"PREPAY PLUS - $0 -"|"0"|"0"|"0"|"0"|"0"|"0"
"2015-10-06"|"592"|"050"|"48836832"|"Apple Inc"|"Apple iPhone 5S (A1530)"|"Talk and Text Connect Flexi Plan"|"46.5744"|"1"|"1"|"0"|"0"|"0"
"2015-10-06"|"409"|"720"|"113755347"|"Samsung Korea"|"Samsung SM-G360G"|"$29 CARRYOVER PLAN"|"108.486"|"1"|"1"|"1"|"0"|"0"
"2015-10-06"|"742"|"620"|"19840943"|"Apple Inc"|"Apple iPhone S (A1530)"|"PREPAY STD - $0 - #2"|"18.9218"|"1"|"1"|"0"|"0"|"0"
"2015-10-06"|"387"|"180"|"0"|"HUAWEI Technologies Co Ltd"|"HUAWEI HUAWEI G526-L11"|"PREPAY STD - $1 - #4"|"0"|"0"|"0"|"0"|"0"|"0"
"2015-10-06"|"731"|"570"|"2258243"|"Samsung Korea"|"Samsung SM-N910U"|"Business Freedom"|"2.15363"|"1"|"0"|"0"|"0"|"0"
"2015-10-06"|"556"|"910"|"13332272"|"Samsung Korea"|"Samsung GT-I9505"|"$49 Plan"|"12.7146"|"1"|"1"|"0"|"0"|"0"
```

I am interested in column names 9-13

```
$ head -n1 test6 | tr '|' '\n' | cat -n
     1  "Rec_Open_Date"
     2  "MSISDN"
     3  "IMEI"
     4  "Data_Volume_Bytes"
     5  "Device_Manufacturer"
     6  "Device_Model"
     7  "Product_Description"
     8  "Data_Volume_MB"
     9  ">20MB/30"
    10  ">200MB/30"
    11  ">2048MB/30"
    12  ">5120MB/30"
    13  ">10240MB/30"
```

I want to use awk to get the names out but I want to control the order. This works but the ordering is not as I wuld like:

```
$ awk -F'|' -v q='"' 'NR==1{for (i=9;i<=NF;i++) col[i]=$i}; END { for (i in col) print col[i]}' test6;
">200MB/30"
">2048MB/30"
">5120MB/30"
">10240MB/30"
">20MB/30"
$
```

I would like the ordering to be like this top to bottom, and/or reversed, that is 9-13 or 13-9. I have left the numbers(9-13) in the output for clarity, I don't want them in my output. I want my output to be like my awk output above. **Can this be done in awk or do I have to use something else?**

```
9  ">20MB/30"
10  ">200MB/30"
11  ">2048MB/30"
12  ">5120MB/30"
13  ">10240MB/30"
```

This is what I want and/or in reverse, I'm hoping it can be done from awk.

```
">20MB/30"
">200MB/30"
">2048MB/30"
">5120MB/30"
">10240MB/30"
```

### **EDIT1 my answer from below answers**

the key for was this `for (i = 9; i <= NF; i++) print col[i]` v this `for (i in col) print col[i]`

```
$ awk -F'|' -v q='"' 'NR==1{for (i=9;i<=NF;i++) col[i]=$i}; END { for (i = NF; i >= 9; i--) print col[i]}' test6
">10240MB/30"
">5120MB/30"
">2048MB/30"
">200MB/30"
">20MB/30"

$ awk -F'|' -v q='"' 'NR==1{for (i=9;i<=NF;i++) col[i]=$i}; END { for (i = 9; i <= NF; i++) print col[i]}' test6
">20MB/30"
">200MB/30"
">2048MB/30"
">5120MB/30"
">10240MB/30"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not work reliably because `awk` arrays are associative and the order in which the array is scanned depends on implementation. `GNU awk` makes it possible to control the scanning order to some extent. However, since you know the indices, you can easily use them directly, as suggested by Michael:

```
awk -F'|' -v q='"' 'NR==1{for (i=9;i<=NF;i++) col[i]=$i}; END { for (i = 9; i <= 13; i++) print col[i]}' test6
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see if the following does what you need:

```
awk -F'|' -v q='"' '{if(FNR==1){for (i=0;i<=NF;i++) print $i;}}' test6
```

Answer (score 0):

A short pipeline can do this:

```
head -1 input | cut -f9-13 -d'|' | tr '|' '\n'
```

*to give*

```
">20MB/30"
">200MB/30"
">2048MB/30"
">5120MB/30"
">10240MB/30"
```

but this assumes that there are no pipe symbols within quotes

and a version using `awk` with the same assumption:

```
awk -vFPAT='[^"|]+' 'NR==1{for(i=9;i<=13;i++){print $i}}' input
```

*this gives*:

```
>20MB/30
>200MB/30
>2048MB/30
>5120MB/30
>10240MB/30
```